# How do I find (not remove) duplicates in an NSDictionary of NSArrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

The title pretty much says it all, but just to clarify: I have an NSMutableDictonary containing several NSMutableArrays. What I would like to do is find any value that is present in multiple arrays (there will not be any duplicates in a single array) and return that value. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** For clarity's sake I will specify some of my variables:
linesMutableDictionary contains a list of Line objects (which are a custom NSObject subclass of mine)

pointsArray is an array inside each Line object and contains the values I am trying to search through.

Basically I am trying to find out which lines share common points (the purpose of my app is geometry based)

Comment: can i see the interface definition of a `Line`?

Comment: @interface Lines: NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *pointsArray;
}

Comment: and are you setting certain keys to be different Line objects?

Comment: the keys are the identifiers for each Line object, the values for the keys are the Line objects themselves

Comment: updated my post to work with Line objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSValue*)checkForDupes:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict {
    NSMutableArray *derp = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
        Line *temp = (Line*)[dict objectForKey:key];
        for (NSValue *val in [temp pointsArray]) {
            if ([derp containsObject:val])
                return val;
        }
        [derp addObjectsFromArray:[temp pointsArray]];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

this should work

Comment: Thank you for quick response! However, I believe you misunderstood my question (or I misunderstood your code). I have edited my question to clarify

Comment: Thank you very much for both your answer and your tolerance for my mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

If by duplicates you mean returning `YES` to `isEqual:` you could first make an NSSet of all the elements (NSSet cannot, by definition, have duplicates):

```
NSMutableSet* allElements = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for (NSArray* array in [dictionary allValues]) {
    [allElements addObjectsFromArray:array];
}
```

Now you loop through the elements and check if they are in multiple arrays

```
NSMutableSet* allDuplicateElements = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for (NSObject* element in allElements) {
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSArray* array in [dictionary allValues]) {
        if ([array containsObject:element]) count++;
        if (count > 1) {
            [allDuplicateElements addObject:element];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have your duplicate elements and don't forget to release `allElements` and `allDuplicateElements`.

Comment: That would be a set of arrays not a set of the elements in the arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry but my original question was misworded, and for what I meant this code will not work. I have edited my question to correct my mistake.  Could you please show me how to edit your code to work now?